How to create a keyvault and use its secrets in the same Bicep template?
This is what I want to do:

Create KeyVault and secrets
Create a MySql DB and reference the username/password from the KeyVault
Create an App Service and set the connection string using the username/password from the KeyVault

I read that I should use a Managed Identity for this, but I am not sure if I use it correctly.
This is my Bicep file:
param appNamePrefix string = 'foobar'
param location string = 'West Europe'
param env string = 'dev'
param mysqlDbName string = '${appNamePrefix}-${env}'
param mysqlUsername string = 'admin'

@secure()
@minLength(10)
param mysqlPassword string

resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31'  = {
  location: location
  name: toLower('${appNamePrefix}-uami-${env}')
}

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' = {
  name: '${appNamePrefix}-keyvault-${env}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: managedIdentity.properties.principalId
        permissions: {
          secrets: ['get']
        }
      }
    ]
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      bypass: 'None'
    }
  }
}

resource mysqlAdminUsernameSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: 'adminUsername'
  properties: {
    value: mysqlUsername
  }
}

resource mysqlAdminPasswordSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: 'adminPassword'
  properties: {
    value: mysqlPassword
  }
}
resource mysqlServer 'Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers@2023-06-30' = {
  name: '${appNamePrefix}-${env}-mysql-server'
  location: location
  sku: {
    tier: 'Burstable'
    name: 'Standard_B1s' 
  }
  properties: {
    createMode: 'Default'
    administratorLogin: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${mysqlAdminUsernameSecret.properties.secretUri})'
    administratorLoginPassword: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${mysqlAdminPasswordSecret.properties.secretUri})'
    version: '8.0'
    storage: {
      storageSizeGB: 20
      iops: 360
      autoGrow: 'Enabled'
    }
    backup: {
      backupRetentionDays: 7
      geoRedundantBackup: 'Disabled'
    }
    network: {
      delegatedSubnetResourceId: subnet.id
    }
  }

  resource db 'databases' = {
    name: mysqlDbName
  }
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2023-01-01' = {
  name: '${appNamePrefix}-plan-${env}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'B1'
    tier: 'Basic'
  }
}

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: '${appNamePrefix}-app-${env}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      connectionStrings: [
        {
          name: 'DefaultConnection'
          type: 'MySql'
          connectionString: 'Server=${mysqlServer.name}.mysql.database.azure.com;Database=${mysqlDbName};User=@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${mysqlAdminUsernameSecret.properties.secretUri});Password=@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${mysqlAdminPasswordSecret.properties.secretUri})'
        }
      ]
    }
    keyVaultReferenceIdentity: managedIdentity.id
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
}

output appEndpoint string = appService.properties.defaultHostName


The error I am getting is:
ERROR: {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-yyyy-dev/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/main","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidParameterValue","message":"Invalid value given for parameter administratorLogin. Specify a valid parameter value."}]}}
I think I could deploy the KeyVault first and then use a parameter file that references the KeyVault. But then I would have more deployment steps.

it should work. what is the issue you have at the moment ? any specific error ?

@Thomas sorry, I completely forgot to add the error. I added it now to the question. It simply says the parameter (the string that refers to the KV secret) is invalid.

Ho yeah, this should be changed: administratorLogin: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${mysqlAdminUsernameSecret.properties.secretUri})'

administratorLogin: mysqlUsername

and same for the password on the database resource

Have you tried using reference() function. @AndreasF

For the best practices, you need to call keyvault secrets in a module. I have coded a sample based on your origin code, to simplify the process, I ignored the deployment of the app service.
main.bicep
param appNamePrefix string = 'foobar'
param location string = 'West Europe'
param env string = 'dev'
@secure()
param mysqlUsername string

@secure()
@minLength(10)
param mysqlPassword string

resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31'  = {
  location: location
  name: toLower('${appNamePrefix}-uami-${env}')
}

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' = {
  name: '${appNamePrefix}-keyvault-${env}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: managedIdentity.properties.principalId
        permissions: {
          secrets: ['get']
        }
      }
    ]
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      bypass: 'None'
    }
  }
}

resource mysqlAdminUsernameSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: 'adminUsername'
  properties: {
    value: mysqlUsername
  }
}

resource mysqlAdminPasswordSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: 'adminPassword'
  properties: {
    value: mysqlPassword
  }
}

module sql 'sql.bicep' = {
  name: 'sqlDeployment'
  params: {
    adminLogin: keyVault.getSecret('adminUsername')
    adminPassword: keyVault.getSecret('adminPassword')
    appNamePrefix: appNamePrefix
    env: env
    location: location
    mysqlDbName: 'dbtest'
  }
}


sql.bicep
param location string
param env string
param mysqlDbName string
@secure()
param adminLogin string
@secure()
param adminPassword string

resource mysqlServer 'Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers@2023-06-30' = {
  name: '${appNamePrefix}-${env}-mysql-server'
  location: location
  sku: {
    tier: 'Burstable'
    name: 'Standard_B1s' 
  }
  properties: {
    createMode: 'Default'
    administratorLogin: adminLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: adminPassword
    version: '8.0'
    storage: {
      storageSizeGB: 20
      iops: 360
      autoGrow: 'Enabled'
    }
    backup: {
      backupRetentionDays: 7
      geoRedundantBackup: 'Disabled'
    }
    network: {
      delegatedSubnetResourceId: subnet.id
    }
  }

  resource db 'databases' = {
    name: mysqlDbName
  }
}


